# reverse linked lists recursively

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

I have a problem with an algorithm which reverses Linked Lists recursively in Python.

```
def reverse(lis, prev = None):
    if lis.next != None:
        reverse(lis.next, lis)
    lis.next = prev
```

Input: `3 1 4`

Output: `3`

Any idea why its not working?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak this question definitely does **not** belong on codereview, as it doesn't work and the question isn't asking for general advice on how to improve the code, but how to fix a malfunction.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the root of your linked list has changed as well: after altering the list, your element `3` is indeed **the last element**, your function better returns the root as well:

```
def reverse(lis, prev = None):
    if lis.next != None:
        temp = lis.next
        lis.next = prev
        return reverse(temp, lis)
    else:
        return lis # the new root
```

so now you call it with:

```
oldroot = ... #construct linked list
newroot = reverse(oldroot)
print(newroot)
```

So your function is correct, but you have the wrong linked list element in your hands after the operation.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like some functional programming exercise, so I present you a functional solution (it copies the list):

```
def reverse(link, rest=None):
    if link is None:
        return rest
    return reverse(link.next, LinkedList(link.value, rest))

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, value=None, next=None):
        self.next = next
        self.value = value
    def print(self):
        print(self.value)
        if self.next is not None:
            self.next.print()

def to_linked_list(items):
    if len(items) == 0:
        return None
    return LinkedList(items[0], to_linked_list(items[1:]))

to_linked_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).print()
# 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
reverse(to_linked_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])).print()
# 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Comment: Nice to present a functional solution. One advice i would give is to override the `__str__` function instead of using the `.print` method. But +1!

Answer (score 2):

In place instead of creating a new chain:

```
def reverse_linked_list(node, prev=None):
    if node.next is None:
        node.next = prev
        return node
    root_node = reverse_linked_list(node.next, node)
    node.next = prev
    return root_node
```